# Import java class using bash

Tags: java, bash

I'm trying to start bash script with next row
`java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $SOAPUI_CLASSPATH com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner "$@"`

But result contains ClassNotFoundException
`[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does it have execute permissions? Try a chmod +x scriptname and then ./scriptname.

Comment: Do you have $SOAPUI_CLASSPATH set?

Comment: Same error with chmod +x

Comment: Also, the -x flag in the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash -x`) could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure SOAPUI_CLASSPATH is set to the location of the sopui jar file, not just the folder that the jar files are in.